# Static/Global variables problems

Tags: class, actionscript, static, global-variables, syntax-error

```
    //main.fla
    var skill1 = addChild(girl2.skill1);
```

i want to access the skill1 var in girl2.as, but it didn't work.

The error was shown : 

1119: Access of possibly undefined property skill1 through a reference with static type Icons.chars:girl2.

```
    //girl2.as
    package Icons.chars
    {

import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class girl2 extends charsel {

public static var skill1:Loader, url1:URLRequest;

public function girl2 () {
    skill1 = new Loader();
    url1 = new URLRequest("skills/nami/skill4.png")
        skill1.load(url1);
```

I tried in charsel.as and it worked

```
//charsel.as
package Icons.chars
{

import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class charsel extends MovieClip {

protected var originalPosition:Point;
public static var player1:MovieClip, player2:MovieClip, player3:MovieClip;
```

I tried to access player1 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would want to use a static modifier in this case. Note, that even though you have declared skill1 as a static it will actually become available only when you create an instance of the girl2 class - as you creating it in the constructor (also note, that you should name your classes with a capital letter, so this should be Girl2).

So, I would either remove all static modifiers for public variables or, if there are any specific reasons for that, use a static initialiser to instantiate skill1 variable:

```
public class girl2 extends charsel {

public static var skill1:Loader, url1:URLRequest;

{
skill1 = new Loader();
skill1.addEventListener(...); // event handlers should be static as well
skill1.load(...);
}

public function girl2 () {
```

Comment: I did what u said, 1119: Access of possibly undefined property skill1 through a reference with static type Icons.chars:girl2.